# Titlebar Min/Max/Close Buttons Stuck in Taskbar

Tags: skype, minimize, maximized, gnome-tweaks

Sometime recently the min/max/close buttons for applications started appearing the taskbar, to the right of my clock. I didn't enforce this setting this deliberately, and I think it started happening after a Skype update or use (could be wrong about that). My Skype window is missing the min/max/close buttons now, and it wasn't before. Running gnome tweaks, and dash to panel, but can't find any solution in those, nor in Skype. My clock used to always be at the bottom right. Thank you for any ideas to fix this. I wasn't able to find a solution in a forum search. Ubuntu 20.04.02 LTS, Gnome 3.36.8, X11 Windowing.
[image: The offending element]

Comment: Disable all your extensions, then enable them one by one to see which extension is causing this behavior.

Comment: Disabling dash-to-panel gives me the standard dash, but the buttons persist. I tried disabling the extensions, and snooping around in dconf-editor. The buttons act on the active window.

Comment: Thanks vanadium, I found it. Your method worked on my second try, after an update and restart. "Pixel Saver" was the culprit. I replaced it with "No Title Bar - Forked" (which has more options) and the buttons no longer appear in the dash or panel.